# Как изменить стиль trackBar

Tags: c#

Я пишу что-то на подобии видео плеера. Не могу понять как изменить стиль trackBar то есть то что двигается и отображение самой полосы.

Comment: опишите подробнее. WinForms или WPF? Или может вообще ASP.NET? Что именно хотите изменить?

Comment: WinForms хотелось бы сделать нечто подобное этому http://rghost.ru/50605653/image.png

Comment: Кастомизация и WinForms — достаточно далёкие друг от друга понятия. Удачи вам!

Answer (score 2):

На WinForms решение данной задачи очень трудоёмко и весьма нетривиально, т.к. отсутствует официальная поддержка скинирования и кастомизации. В связи с этим рекомендую перейти на `Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)` - технология, специально предназначенная для решения подобных задач. Её отличие от `WinForms` заключается в том, что для визуализации приложения программист, вместо того, чтобы самому писать код графического интерфейса, пишет разметку на `XAML` (расширение `XML` для `WPF`), по которой интерпритатор потом сам генерирует исполняемый код с использованием библиотек DirectX, что значительно расширяет возможности визуализации и повышает производительность за счёт делегирования задач визуализации процессору видеокарты. [Вот хороший ресурс](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/info_WPF.php) для изучения WPF. Разрабатывая под `WPF` можно упростить себе задачу, используя специализированную среду разработки `Expression Blend`, которая сгенерирует большую часть разметки сама. [На том же ресурсе](http://professorweb.ru/my/expression_blend/base/level1/info_eb4.php) есть неплохие обучающие материалы по `Expression Blend 4` (на сегодняшний день актуальна 5-ая версия, но умея пользоваться 4-й, использование 5-й не составит труда).